# Reasoning behind the 'Z' key being the shading swap key

Tags: shortcut

I know, this sounds like a stupid question for someone who has been using Blender as long as I have to ask, but I am curious. Does Blender's use of the <kbd>Z</kbd> key be the viewport shader key have a specific meaning? Or is this just a random key they used because the other ones were taken. It would *seem* logical I guess for <kbd>shft</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to be the shader swap key,  but I guess they couldn't because that was already used. Does anybody have any answer for this?

Comment: Probably just random, but if you don't like it you can always change it.

Comment: I think it has been choosed because it's a function that for some tasks can be called very often, and a lot of users have the mouse on the right hand and the left bottom part of the keyboard under their left hand.

Comment: poor german people... Z and Y are swapped...

Comment: I always use English keyboard for working. Almost all programs, including coding is layed out for English keys.